# iOS: How to load image from storage

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I've saved an image to storage using this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, 
                               @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Now, how can I load that image into an image view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I now use:

```
//Load the asset URL from my photo object
NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:photo.photoURL];

ALAssetsLibrary*  myasset = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
//If the image was found
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    //Get the full resolution image
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        //Get the orientation of the image
        ALAssetOrientation orientation = [[myasset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] intValue];
        //Set the image view image
        [self.BigImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:1.0 orientation:orientation]];
    }
};
//If the image isn't available
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't get the image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    [self.BigImageView setImage:nil];
};

[myasset assetForURL:asseturl
    resultBlock:resultblock
    failureBlock:failureblock];
```

Answer (score 2):

Image views have an `image` property.  Assign the image to it.

**Edit:** If you want to save a persistent reference to the entry in the photo album, don't use that function to save it, use [`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum%3ametadata%3acompletionBlock%3a) instead.  The completion block will be passed an `assetURL` parameter.

Comment: No, sorry. Once I've left the app and want to view the image again, how can I load it into the image view?

Comment: Thanks, but what's the metadata? Could you write a bit of example code please?

Comment: @ToddDavies my understanding is that you needn't supply metadata if you don't have any; instead you're just going to keep the `assetURL` as Jim suggests, and use that in future to obtain a `UIImage`.